# Object declared at the end of class?

Tags: c++, class

This is not my code, but is similar to what I am trying to do right now:

```
    class b_bug: public organism
    {
    public:
        void birth(int e,int f)
        {
            x=e;
            y=f;
            life=0;
            arrays[e][f]=2;
            a++;
        }

        void moves();

        void breed();

        void death()
        {
            arrays[x][y]=0;
        }

    }bugs[100000];
```

I wanted to know what bugs[100000] is and why is it declared there? Is there a way to declare it somewhere else?

I know this is a derived class so can i declare it somewhere else in a way that I can access and use it in main as well as other derived classes

Comment: It creates an array of 100000 `b_bug` s with the name `bugs`. You can declare `b_bug bugs[100000]` wherever you want, so long as the compiler can see the full type of `b_bug`.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know what bugs[100000] is

It is a declarator. It declares a variable. `bugs` is the name of the variable, and `[100000]` declares that the variable is an array of 100000 objects.

> and why is it declared there

Presumably because the author of the program needed to declare that variable. It's impossible for us to determine the reason in better detail than that. You could try asking the author or see if the code has documentation regarding the variable.

> Is there a way to declare it somewhere else?

Sure. Variables do not need to be in the same statement as the definition of the type of that variable. Instead of

```
type_definition variable_declaration;
```

You can write

```
type_definition;
type_name variable_declaration;
```

In this case:

```
class b_bug: public organism {
    // definition omitted for brevity
};
b_bug bugs[100000];
```

You can even declare the variable inside a different scope when you declare it separately from the type definition.